# APP CONNECT BUG VERSIONS - 2022 - UPDATED! Flutter & iOS & Android

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Why is there this bug in AppConnect?

When uploading a version 1.0.5, I enter TestFlight and it is seen loading version 1.0.5.

but when I refresh the page, it shows me up to version 1.0.3:

[image: version 1.0.5]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Flutter and is 100% Apple's side. Sometimes it takes many hours. Please, avoid using upper case, hashtags and other languages other than English.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. AppStore Connect is processing the archive you sent to TestFlight. Sometimes it's a long process (can take also 30/40 minutes). When processing is completed, the archive will be shown and will be clickable.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for fast answer; I was waiting for 5 hours when I was upgrading to 1.0.4  and nothing.. -.- ; so I tried with new version... the same..?¿???¿????¿¿?¿?¿?

Comment: Sometimes an error can occur while processing your archive. Check your email for any communication from AppStore Connect.